# Does SqlDbType.DateTime not store seconds?

Tags: c#, datetime, sql-server-2005, ado.net, sqlcommand

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

I am using a `SqlCommand cmd.Parameters` of `SqlDbType.DateTime` to create a record in the database.

Seconds are not being stored in the database. The field in the db is of type datetime.

Do I need to do something special to save seconds, or does `SqlDbType.DateTime` not do that?

Comment: Are you positive the parameter value has seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SqlDbType.DateTime` maps to SQL's `DATETIME` datatype, which is accurate to 3.33 milliseconds.  It sounds like you may be putting your values into a `SMALLDATETIME` field in SQL server, which is only accurate to the minute.  `SqlDbType.DateTime` parameter would be the correct choice for use with both `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server DateTime stores time with millisecond accuracy (not quite right it rounds to .003 .007 etc)

Smalldatetime, however, stores dates such that the seconds are always :00. You have probably used smalldatetime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx